# Questions filtered by favourite tags--no favourite tags available

Tags: support, tag-watching, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I'm new here and have been playing around and trying out various things. I might be dumb but I can't work out how to use favourite tags to filter questions. I've set a small number of favourite tags on Stack Overflow but whenever I go to the 'Filtered Questions' section on Stack Exchange I don't see any of them--the list is empty (I can, however, see the complete list of my sites).
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I just have a bookmark where I or'd them all together

Comment: Have you tried [manually syncing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kG0lQ.png) your favourite tags using the re-sync link in the "show details" box of the Favorite Tags filter? Or does the Favorite Tags filter not appear at all?

Comment: @tim-stone, the Fav Tags filter is there but without the re-sync link. It only says 'No favorite tags found'.

Comment: I've just tried adding a screenshot but turns out I'm not reputable enough ;) Off to gain some reputation!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I can see them now! So--excuse my answering my own question--my guess is it can take a long time to sync favorite tags (even well over 12h) whereas **the link to manual syncing won't show up as long as the list is empty**.

If someone more competent can (dis)confirm this, it would be helpful.

Comment: This is correct-- favorite tags are cached for a day, and currently the "re-sync favorite tags" link is only shown once you have at least one favorite tag. I'll update the behavior to make sure this link is shown even when you have zero favorite tags.